# Python list processing

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and wonder what is the "pythonic" way for processing this type of list.  For maintainability I like function tables like this:

```
    def read_book():  print('reading book')
    def watch_movie(): print('watching movie')

    types =  [
        ['book', 'Dizzy Blondes', 'read_book'],
        ['movie', 'GWTW', 'watch_movie']
    ]
```

In C language I would do something like this:

```
    NAME=0
    TITLE=1
    FUNCTION=2
```

And access the table with:

```
    for i in range(len(types)):
        print(f"name is {types[i][NAME]}, \
            title is {types[i][TITLE]}, \
            function is {types[i][FUNCTION]}")
```

Making 'types' a list of dictionaries would mean losing the style I like. I'm trying to avoid this:

```
    types =  [
        {'name':'book', 'title':'Dizzy Blondes',
           'function': 'read_book'},
        {'name':'movie', 'title':'GWTW',
            'function': 'watch_movie'}
    ]
```

My first effort was this:

```
    a2_types = []
    for i in range(len(types)):
        a2_types.append({
            'name': types[i][0],
            'title': types[i][1],
            'function': types[i][2]
        })
```

Then accessing the table by:

```
    for i in range(len(a2_types)):    
        print(f"name is {a2_types[i]['name']}, \
            title is {a2_types[i]['title']}, \
            function is {a2_types[i]['function']}")
```

I didn't like that at all, my next try gave:

```
    idx = {'name': 0, 'title': 1, 'function': 2}
```

Then accessing with this:

```
    for i in range(len(types)):
        print(f"name is {types[i][idx['name']]}, \
            title is {types[i][idx['title']]}, \
            function is {types[i][idx['function']]}")
```

At this point I'm going back to C language style, I highly prefer clean and simple code (yes I have maintenance experience) but I'm wondering if I missed something.

Comment: What sort of maintenance are you imagining here? You say "function table" then show a list of lists. Then you say you don't like dictionaries because... they lose your style? And the thing you refer to as "C-style" is a dictionary lookup of strings? My head is frankly spinning.

Comment: A few things: 1) I would suggest just making a `class` to store your types, with the attributes `name`, `title`, `function`. You can then override `__str__` for the class to always get your nicely formatted output. 2) `for i in range(len(a2_types))` is used in your case equivalently to `for item in a2_types` where here `item` is the same as your `a2_types[i]`. This adds some readability.

Comment: Silvio, 'function table' was loose terminology, I think function dispatch table is closer.  I thought it was horrible when I saw one used in a million lines of code project decades ago but for some reason I threw it in this hobby project.  You missed the lack of quotes in NAME=0, TITLE=1, FUNCTION.  In C those would have been #define NAME 0 ...   Also the quotes around 'read_books' and 'watch_movies' were my error, should have unquoted them after defining the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kraigolas stated, the best way is to probably make a `class` with the `name`, `title`, and `function` as attributes.

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, title, function):
        self.name = name
        self.title = title
        self.function = function
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"name is {self.name}, title is {self.title}, function is {self.function}"

types = [
    Item("book", "Dizzy Blondes", "read_book"),
    Item("movie", "GWTW", "watch_movie")
]

for t in types:
    print(t)
```

You can even directly pass in a python `function` as your function

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, title, function):
        self.name = name
        self.title = title
        self.function = function
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"name is {self.name}, title is {self.title}"

def readBook(self):
    print(f"reading book {self.title}")

types = [
    Item("book", "Dizzy Blondes", readBook),
    Item("movie", "GWTW", lambda self: print(f"watching {self.title}"))
]

for t in types:
    t.function(t)
```

Although I suggest that if you are using this method, it may be better off to create a new `class` for each object type

Answer (score 1):

Python generally uses objects to bind functions and data together. Try something like:

```py
class Media:
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title

class Book(Media):
    def interact(self):
        print('reading book', self.title)

class Movie(Media):
    def interact(self):
        print('watching movie', self.title) 

types = [
    Book('Dizzy Blondes'),
    Movie('GWTW'),
]

for media in types:
    print('kind of media is:', media.__class__.__name__)
    print('title is:', media.title)
    media.interact()
```

If you generally want tabular data, there's other tools for that. Please let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: It would make more sense in this case to make an `Item` class with the attributes `name`, `title`, and `function`

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.  I agree, I should be using a class to bind the name to the function.  This was a trivial example of what I'm doing, a hobby project I've developed bottom up to learn Python.  I started with scripts to parse xml files and create, update and access MySQL tables and later added QT GUI's, which I also had to learn.  This type of 'function table' is used to add dynamic GUI buttons, labels, window sizes and functions.  I retired in 2007 but decided to learn Python and refresh my skills to stop (or at least slow down) brain rot.